# How to set up external library from git in c++

Tags: c++, cmake

New to C++, and trying to install [this](https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX) to help handle .xlsx files. As far as I understand, installation of / configuration of external libraries varies from case to case. There are no instructions in the READEME.me file, I have tried the `make` and `cmake` commands in terminal but I am unsure what file I need to direct it to etc. I have already cloned the repository.

Could anyone with experience in c++ open source libraries possibly help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I think what you need is to learn how both *make* and *CMake* work.

If I were you, this is what I would have done:

```
$ cd path_to_OpenXLSX_repository
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="Path where you want to install the library" ..
$ make install
```

For some explanation:

- Create a build directory (in order to not pollute your repository with build things)
- `cmake ..` will read the CMakeLists.txt file located in `../` and generate the Makefile
- The variable [CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) allows you to set the path where you want to install the library.
  You can get rid of it if you want to use the default.
- `make install` to build and install the library

But you really should take some time to learn about *CMake* :)

---

**Edit:**

Actually, it seems that they have not set any install rule (hence the empty output of `make install`). So only running `make` will build and generate your library.

So it becomes:

```
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
```

And then, in "repo_path/build/install/lib/", you'll see your shared library called in your case: *libOpenXLSX.so*

Comment: I tried this, up to the Cmake instruction, and received the error message 'Cmake error: the source directory "/OpenXLSX/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt'

Comment: @Maria You missed the `..` argument, when you typed `cmake ..`

Comment: Oh. thank you. The Cmake worked when I added '..', when I type 'make install' in the build folder no error occurs but there is no success feedback. How do I tell if it worked?

Comment: @Maria You're welcome. If no error occurs then it worked :) If you want to check, go to your install dir and check if the generated lib appears here.

Comment: The lib folder is there but empty- should it be?

Comment: @Maria Well I can't tell, I don't know where you have installed your lib, did you specify the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ? If yes, it should be there, if not, you should check for an install dir (read the CMakeLists.txt) or in /usr/local/...

Comment: From the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), it seems to be an install dir defined as: ${[CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR.html)}/install

Comment: @Maria I have edited my answer with what was missing.